# Add calendar jquery image to datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am not sure how to add the `ui-icon ui-icon-calendar` class as a datepicker image beside the text field. I want something like this: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#icon-trigger, but it should have the jquery calendar image.

Comment: Just see the official documentation: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#icon-trigger

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
<script>
        $(function() {
            $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
                showOn: "button",
                buttonImage: "http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif",
                buttonImageOnly: true
            });
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you click the view source button below the example you linked to, you'll see something like this:

```
$('#field').datepicker({        
    buttonImage: '/images/calendar_icon.png'
});
```

Comment: I don't have the calendar_icon.png in my download. so I wanted to use the ui-icon-calendar image.

Answer (score 0):

by this we can clear the given date from the field though the field is readonly.It should be readonly not to be given by user must be choosen from datepicker.

html:

```
$("#datepickerID").datepicker({          
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "images/calendar.png",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    buttonText: "Select date",
    minDate : 0,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    closeText: 'Clear',
    onClose: function () {
        var event = arguments.callee.caller.caller.arguments[0];
        // If "Clear" gets clicked, then really clear it
        if ($(event.delegateTarget).hasClass('ui-datepicker-close')) {
            $(this).val('');
        }
    }
});
```